# Parsing Error with EJS file while compiling on codesandbx

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, ejs

I get an expected error and I am unsure what is wrong with my file because I was following a tutorial. It seems that I get a parsing error and the error lies in the first line

[Error in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYlWz.png)

below I have my code

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YelpCamp</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/landing.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript" async></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
        <% if(error && error.length > 0){ %>
            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                <%= error %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
        <% if(success && success.length > 0){ %>
            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                <%= success %>
            </div>
        <% } %>
    </div>

    <div id="landing-header">
        <h1>Welcome to YelpCamp!</h1>
        <a href="/campgrounds" class="btn btn-lg btn-success">View All Campgrounds</a>
        <p>
           <form action="/campgrounds" method="GET" class="form-inline">
               <div class="form-group">
                   <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Campground search..." class="form-control">
                   <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default">
               </div>
           </form>
       </p>
    </div>

    <ul class="slideshow">
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
      <li></li>
    </ul>

<%- include ('./partials/footer'); -%>```
````

Comment: it better to share your codesanbox url